# Angular/Typescript - Type<any> and how to use if I know that a specific property exists

Tags: angular, typescript

I have in my Angular code for each component a parameter

```
myType: string
```

When I try to route I have as type `route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot` which has the nested parameter `component: Type<any> | null;` - with `Type<any>`

Right now I access the property `myType` like

```
route.component['myType'] === 'chkProperty'
```

which causes annotation with the remark that I should use the dot notation. Writing like `route.component.myType` causes an error with the hint that `myType is not in Type<any>`

I would like to use a specific type (=redefine the `Type<any>`) and use the dot notation.

Comment: You could create an interface with a "myType" field and cast your route.component as such, so (route.component as MyInterface).myType would work, but it's not really more type safe. I guess it's either that or wrap the whole interface so that it behave as you want

Comment: I need to cast it like `(route.component as unknown as MyInterface)` ==> why first as `unknown`???

Comment: The types are too distinct I guess, unknown is assignable to everything so it bypass the error, may as well cast directly as "any" in that case but it goes against what typescript is trying to accomplish